# C++ input from array to file through function

Tags: c++, string, file, function

I'm currently studying basic c++, and I've encountered a problem that I can't deal with. In the below code you can see my program. What's bad about it, is that from the `cout << word;` I can see the content of my text file, but the `cout << astring` doesn't show me anything. Could anyone please point me out the mistake?

P.s. It has to be done with functions.

```
void read(string word);
int main()
{

string astring;
read(astring);
cout << astring;

return 0;
}
void read(string word)
{
ifstream duom ("info.txt");

if (duom.is_open())
{


while(!duom.eof()) 
{

    getline(duom, word);
    cout << word;
}
}
else cout << "File couldn't be opened";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `read` takes a copy to the string and reads into this temporary. To read into the input parameter, use reference like so:

```
void read(string& word);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a reference to the function: `void read(string& word);` so that you can later use *the actual* `word`, not its local copy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the read function doesn't change astring in main, astring is passed to the read function it is not *returned from* the read function. You should change read, either like this

```
void read(string& word); // pass a reference to a string to read

int main()
{
    string astring;
    read(atring);
```

or like this

```
string read(); // return a string from read

int main()
{
    string astring = read();
```

The second version is generally preferred.

Answer (score 0):

you should use reference or pointer like

```
void read(string& word); 
or
void read(string *word);
```